# Accuracy fixed at 50% keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to tensorflow and keras, I am trying to follow a tutorial on keras (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qFJeN9V1ZsI min.38:40) and everything seems to work but as soon as I run the fit, accuracy remains almost fixed at 50% and I can't understand why, can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy

import numpy as np
from random import randint
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

train_labels = []
train_samples = []

for i in range(50):
    random_younger = randint(13,64)
    train_samples.append(random_younger)
    train_labels.append(1)
    
    random_older = randint(65,100)
    train_samples.append(random_older)
    train_labels.append(0)

for i in range(950):
    random_younger = randint(13,64)
    train_samples.append(random_younger)
    train_labels.append(0)
    
    random_older = randint(65,100)
    train_samples.append(random_older)
    train_labels.append(1)

train_label = np.array(train_labels)
train_samples = np.array(train_samples)
train_labels, train_labels = shuffle(train_labels, train_labels)

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_train_samples = scaler.fit_transform(train_samples.reshape(-1,1))
scaled_train_samples = np.array(scaled_train_samples)

model = Sequential([
  Dense(units=16, input_shape = (1,), activation='relu'),
  Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
  Dense(units=2, activation='softmax')
])

#model.summary()

train_labels = np.array(train_labels)
scaled_train_samples = np.array(scaled_train_samples)

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.01), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=scaled_train_samples, y=train_labels, batch_size=10, epochs=30, shuffle=True, verbose =2)

input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have code

```
train_labels, train_labels = shuffle(train_labels, train_labels)
```

you shuffle the labels but not the train samples suspect you want

```
train_labels, train_samples= shuffle(train_label, train_samples)
```

this code shuffles the labels and the samples. Also curious why for the first 50 samples you have younger label as 1 and older label as 0, then for next 950 samples
the labels are reversed?

Comment: Thank you very much I hadn't thought about it